# Good map of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I bought Skyrim via Steam and also bought the online Prima game guide.  It touts a whole map section, but fails to provide any kind of map of Skyrim.  (Kind of lame for a game guide to not come with a map.  I give the online guide very low marks.)

So, I would like to know if there is a decent map of Skyrim out there yet.  (Clearly I can just go to the world map, but I am trying to find a place I have not discovered yet.)

Comment: A map comes with the boxed version, someone must have scanned it if its not on the net already.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Guys at [Gamebanshee](http://www.gamebanshee.com/skyrim/mapofskyrim.php) published a really nice annotated map of Skyrim, available as single BIG (2720x1935) image or a 9-pages PDF.

[image]

As reported by @Mehmet and interactive map is available on [Mashupforge](http://mashupforge.com/582/AQOfHyq4Omzp0fEfFIN70sy9yp9X8K/#m=1014&x=-3.25020856&y=-2.10937500&z=3).

Finally there is a nice free app on iTunes that work on iPhone and iPad, called [Dragon Shout](http://itunes.apple.com/app/dragon-shout/id483488468?mt=8) (Android version coming soon hopefully). Here you can see it in action (not the latest version)

Comment: I will just say: waow.

Answer (score 4):

[Check out the interactive zoomable, draggable, searchable map made on Mashupforge.](http://mashupforge.com/582/AQOfHyq4Omzp0fEfFIN70sy9yp9X8K/)

Comment: One of the best maps i must say, allows you to turn off specific icons and makes it easier to search locations and view roads

Answer (score 1):

if you are looking for a map  that would have all the locations marked, there hasn't been enough time for any community to really get that set up. I have played maybe 30 hours of skyrim since it released, and i have yet to explore 3/4 of the map.

a good site to check every once in a while for a map would be: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Main_Page but they dont have one out yet. I should also add that when they get this map added it will be similar to google maps, with a wikipage for each location

EDIT: as One-One has mentioned, here is the skyrim map: http://www.uesp.net/maps/srmap/srmap.shtml. Every single dungeon on the site should have a link to their wiki page, so you will be able to find out lots of useful information

Answer (score 1):

The Gamebanshee map also has an [interactive version](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Map_%28Skyrim%29) online at wikia.com.