# Geopolitical Maps in Elder Scrolls Over Time

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series

I'm looking for a tracking method of the geopolitical story in the Elder Scrolls saga.

Ideally there would be an animated map (a gif for example), with the map evolving to track each empire/dynasty

I have already seen this:

[image]

and this:

[image]

I've already tried searching for each era, but haven't found anything comprehensive.

Comment: I am voting to close this as a recommendation request given what is talked about in [this meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12357/30879) and a similar question [on Skyrim alone](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/35891/30879) was closed for this reason a month ago (despite having been asked almost 6 years ago)

Comment: @Memor-X That's true, but this could easily be edited into being on-topic by simply changing wording a bit. If he were to be asking for how the borders/population has changed throughout the years it wouldn't be necessarely asking for an outside source. However an gif like the asker said, would be ideal because it would be the clearest representation of the evolution of Tamriel

Comment: @Memor-X Heck, upon re-reading the question he didn't even ask for the answer to be an outside source, but only mentioned that a gif would be a good approach (due to its clarity). This question is fine imo.

Comment: @Oak I would disagree.  This is a very obvious external resource request.

Comment: sry for my english, I talk about "gif" because I was, in my head, only on "image search based", I don't thought people create video with map evolution ! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the closest thing I can find; [This History of Tamriel: Every Decade](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLEGFdPcvZ8) is a video which maps out the events that happened throughout the history of Tamriel, **including geopolitical boundaries**. I would suggest if you need a GIF use one of the many YouTube video downloaders then use a second tool to convert the video to a GIF - search for both, you'll find plenty of tools for them.

I for one am quite interested in the very comprehensive lore that sits in the background of each Elder Scrolls title and have spent many an hour perusing the [History of Tamriel](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:History). Although not an image you'll find everything that ever happened - not only on Tamriel but on the Daedric planes too - including **every shift in political alignment**.

From the link above you'll find detailed histories of the three largest dynasties of the empire; [Reman](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Reman_Dynasty), [Septim](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Septim_Dynasty) and [Mede](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Mede_Dynasty). There's also histories of provincial and ancient dynasties such as the [Ayleids](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Lore:Ayleids).

Comment: thx, I forgot to try search video... I was focalized on "map" key word^^
Realy interesting for me !